# Finding areas of different curves in a rectangle

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is the problem:

[image]

So far, I don’t think that any of the answers are correct. For I, f(x) is the top function and g(x) is the bottom function, so the function inside the integral should be f(x) - g(x), not g(x) - f(x). For II, the top function is y = 4, so the function inside the integral should be 4 - f(x). Finally, for III, the bottom function is y = 1, so the function inside the integral should be 1 - g(x).

Is this reasoning correct? If not, can someone explain where it is incorrect? Thank you very much.

Comment: You are correct about what should go into the integral for III, but you didn't integrate it correctly!  You'd end up with the integral of 1 from 1 to 4, which evaluates to 3, then subtract g(x) from that...

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Does this mean that the integral shown for A3 in the picture is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangle is misleading. The integrals don't recognize the bottom of the rectangle, but instead the $x$-axis.

II and III are correct.